# Why did NA27 include 2 Corinthians 13:14?

Tags: textual-criticism

> NA27 2 Cor 1314 Ἡ χάρις τοῦ κυρίου Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ καὶ ἡ ἀγάπη τοῦ θεοῦ καὶ ἡ κοινωνία τοῦ ἁγίου πνεύματος μετὰ πάντων ὑμῶν.
>
> Brooke Foss Westcott and Fenton John Anthony Hort, The New Testament in the Original Greek, vol. 1: Text; vol. 2: Introduction [and] Appendix (Cambridge: Macmillan, 1881).
>
> [Variants]: Nestle-Aland Novum Testamentum Graece. 27th ed. Stuttgart: (Deutsche Bibelgesellschaft, 1993).

It appears that [NA27 includes 2 Corinthians 13:14](https://biblehub.com/whnac/2_corinthians/13.htm) which [in previous editions was apparently excluded as unoriginal](https://biblehub.com/texts/2_corinthians/13-14.htm).

[image: Variants of 2 Cor 13:14]

Why might that be?

Comment: I imagine that since it is an ongoing effort, the edition was revised, revisited.

Comment: I'm hoping to get more information on their decision making process. I mean, it appears to be a very poor candidate!

Comment: Why does it appear to be a very poor candidate?

Comment: Because it was refused multiple times before and the tradition that includes it appears to be Byzantine which in general, I believe is considered less reliable. Of course, I don't know what I'm talking about, really, which is why I asked.

Comment: Also, several Trinitarian frauds have already been outed so this looks like more of the same.

Comment: Are you saying the committee behind this edition of the NT can't revise what they've formerly concluded? What's the point in a critical edition at all in that case? Also, if it were proved beyond doubt authentic, you would deny that it teaches the Trinity anyway. According to you the Trinity was invented far later than the first century, except we have Clement using even stronger language around 96AD: "As God lives, and as Jesus Christ and the Holy Ghost live." The same tying the persons of the Trinity into one category and prerogative.

Comment: It is fascinating to me that Trinitarians do not realize that they see the scriptures through "Trinity-colored glasses". For example, to you this is proof of "Trinity": "As God lives, and as Jesus Christ and the Holy Ghost live."  How can you see that as referring to a "Trinity" unless you have already been conditioned to see it? Clement, I am coming to understand, was a fraud. One of many, many false apostles, false Christ's, false witnesses, false letters, false miracles, fake creeds, etc. that we see mentioned in and around the scriptures.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91614/discussion-between-sola-gratia-and-ruminator).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This passage, the so-called, "Trinitarian Blessing" is included/excluded in the following editions of the GNT:

- Vaticanus (Wilson, Emphatic Diaglott) - included but numbered as v13
- W&H (Hendrickson) - included but numbered as v13
- B&FBS GNT 1904 - included but numbered as v13
- NA27 (Biblegesellschaft) - included but numbered as v13
- UBS4 (Biblegesellschaft) - included but numbered as v13
- NA28 (Biblegesellschaft) - included but numbered as v13
- UBS5 (Biblegesellschaft) - included but numbered as v13
- Souter (Oxford) - included but numbered as v14
- THGNT (Tyndale House) - included but numbered as v13
- SBL (SBL) - included but numbered as v13
- NIV (Zondervan) - included but numbered as v13
- Majority Text (Farstad-Hodges et al, Nelson) - included but numbered as v13
- RP Byzantine Text - included but numbered as v14
- F35 (Pickering - self published) - included but numbered as v14
- OCT (1904, Elpenor) - included but numbered as v13
- TR (TBS)- included but numbered as v14
- Jerome's Vulgate (Biblegesellschaft) - included but numbered as v13

Thus, the INCLUSION of this final verse in 2 Cor is NOT controversial.  It appears to be included in almost all MSS, even early ones.  The verse numbering varies between editions.  UBS4 & UBS5 does not foot-note any significant variations.  However, NA27 & NA28 note some minor variations in the text of the verse but all appear to include the verse.

Note - Each GNT edition above is from a separately published (paper) volume.

Comment: Can you please provide a source? Thanks. +1

Comment: Wow, I appreciate that! Can you tell me which book? As you know, sources are a requirement.

Comment: They are all separate books - each listing above is a separate published book and different edition of the GNT.

Comment: Okay, kewl. So can you make a note in your answer indicating that you copied them from the books? Comments go away. Thanks.

Comment: That is what the list is - each version is listed above in the answer.  Each book contains just one GNT version and each is separately published, individual book containing a different GNT.

Answer (score 1):

According to the late Bruce Metzger:

> 13:13 ὑμῶν.
>   As would be expected, the Textus Receptus, following א﻿ D E K P Ψ most minuscules > it vg syr,  cop goth arm, adds ἀμήν. The text (without ἀμήν) is decisively supported by  א﻿* A B F G 33 90 424 it vg arm eth.

In other words, the bulk of this verse is agreed upon by all major manuscripts; the main difference is that the Byzantine tradition (along with some other manuscripts I might add) added ἀμήν.

This quote is taken from his *A Textual Commentary on the Greek New Testament, Second Edition*, a great resource in general for finding out the reasoning for any of the NA27 or UBS4's decisions. From the preface of the 1st edition:

> The present volume is designed to serve as a companion to the third edition of the United Bible Societies’ Greek New Testament, edited by Kurt Aland, Matthew Black, Carlo M. Martini, Bruce M. Metzger, and Allen Wikgren.
>   One of the chief purposes of the commentary is to set forth the reasons that led the Committee, or a majority of the members of the Committee, to adopt certain variant readings for inclusion in the text and to relegate certain other readings to the apparatus.

The 2nd edition of Metzger's *Textual Commentary* is then updated for the UBS4. But take into account that the actual Greek texts of the UBS4 and NA27 are purposefully kept the same; they just gave a different textual apparatus to suit different purposes. (I can't comment on [this answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/39736/25621) since I don't have the requisite reputation, but a corollary to this fact is that we shouldn't cite NA27 and UBS4 as if they're two separate sources.)

Bruce Metzger worked on the team for the NA27, so this is as authoritative of an answer as you're going to get for why they included it.

I'm not sure what's going on with biblehub.com on 2 Cor 13:14, but biblehub.com shows more attestation for the inclusion of this verse when it shows passages for [2 Cor 13:13](https://biblehub.com/texts/2_corinthians/13-13.htm). One thing you could do in the future to double check the 1881 edition of Westcott and Hort is to look it up on [archive.org's copy](https://archive.org/details/newtestamentinor01west/page/418).

Comment: Awesome answer and +1. And welcome to the site.